# Double possessive when thing possessed is plural

Tags: grammar, possessives, double-possessive

"This year we planned a cruise with four friends of ours."

I've only ever seen a double possessive with words that are singular. For example, "I am *a* friend of Bob's" or "It's *the* password of Mark's." In the above case, however, it's plural (four). Is having the plural form acceptable, or should this be rephrased?

Comment: "These are three friends of Bob's" is perfectly valid.

Comment: It's fine, though I prefer "...with four of our friends". I think most people would say "it's Mark's password", not "it's the password of Mark's".

Comment: '_I am a friend of Bob_.' Why do you need a second possessive ? '_... planned a cruise with three friends_'. Why make it possessive at all ? '_It's Mark's password._' Why complicate it further ?